# Error C2440 when compiling a library with meson

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, typedef, meson-build, wchar

I have code C++ that I want to compile as a library using **meson** where I get 2 kinds of errors

- **error C2440**: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [19]'
  to 'const PWCHAR'
  -note: Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)
- **error C2664**: '... cannot convert argument 2 from 'const wchar_t [6]'
  to 'PWSTR note: Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)

winnt.h uses typedef for wchar_t:

```
typedef wchar_t WCHAR;
typedef WCHAR *PWCHAR;
```

If I do this in my code I get Error C2440:

```
const PWCHAR Tokens[] = { L"A", L"B", L"C", L"D" };
```

If I change my code that error disappears:

```
 const wchar_t * Tokens[] = { L"A", L"B", L"C", L"D" };
```

I know in C, the type of a string literal is array of char, but in C++, it's array of const char which causes this error.
I also know it is possible to change Zc:strictStrings in VStudio. **But since I compile my code with meson how would I get rid of that error using meson?**

Comment: Wouldn't it potentially be better to use an [std::wstring](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Answer (score 1):

With the definition

```
const PWCHAR Tokens[] = { ... };
```

you declare that `Tokens` is an array of constant *pointers*. The data that those pointers are pointing to are *not* constant.

And as literal strings are constant you can't use them to initialize the array.

The working definition:

```
const wchar_t * Tokens[] = { ... };
```

Or the alternative

```
wchar_t const * Tokens[] = { ... };
```

Here you declare that `Tokens` is an array of (non-constant) pointers to constant `wchar_t` data. Which is correct for literal strings.

If you want to be portable and follow the C++ standard, using `PWCHAR` is simply not possible.

---

If you want the pointers themselves to be constant, you need to add another `const` qualifier for them:

```
wchar_t const * const Tokens[] = { ... };
//              ^^^^^
//              makes the pointers constant
//      ^^^^^
//      makes the data constant
```

Or as mentioned in a comment: Use `std::wstring` (and other standard C++ containers):

```
// Or std::array if the size if known and fixed at compile-time
std::vector<std::wstring> Tokens = { ... };
```